# Load component after user open popup but not destroy it after close popup

Tags: angular

I'm using *ngIf to load the new component (when users open popup), and I don't want to destroy it after user close popup because ngIf does that.

My component has to request http to get data, i don't want alot of request when user open then close popup again.

Is there any way to achieve that instead of move http request part to parent component? Or should I have to use dynamic component ?

Thanks in advance.

It's hard to insert code here, so I use pseudo code:

```
Parent component 
class {
  showIt = false;
  toggleClick() {
    showIt = !showIt;
  }
}

In parent component tempate:
<child-component ngIf='showIt'></child-component>

Child component:
class {
  construct() {
    console.log('Loaded childcomponent') // It prints out every time showIt value is changed
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    Call service to get data  // and I don't want it call multiple times when ngIf recreate child component
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your component inside the modal itself or is it outside, in any template and you are using *ngIf to show/hide it?

Comment: Provide a code snippet to show where you are invoking the service call. It's not easy to help without code as we can interpret what you said in so many ways.

Comment: @ankitSharma the modal itself is a component, so I only need to load it when user open it (via click), then hide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use `*ngIf` initially until the user decides to open it. Once the user opens it, `*ngIf` should evaluate to true.

However, on close button, do not evaluate `*ngIf` to false, rather use `[hidden]` and set this to true. This way the component would only be hidden and not destroyed.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use ngIf just use css display:none to hide the component when it is closed

Comment: so how do i init component in first place ? normal I do it as <component-a ngIf='variable'></component-a>. If i just use css, component will be load before user opens popup.